# How can I use a column name as a variable to create a new column in my SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.1

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT name, gender, age, partners.rate_M, partners.rate_F
  FROM users INNER JOIN partners ON users.id = partners.M_id
```

Currently what I have is:

```
SELECT name, gender, age, partners.rate_M, partners.rate_F
  FROM users INNER JOIN partners
    ON (users.id = partners.M_id OR users.id = partners.F_id)
```

Which slows my system.

M in M_id is the gender, so how can I make the M dynamic?

```
users.gender + '_id' = M_id or F_id
```

Comment: Which selected columns come from the Partners table?

Comment: users.id is the pk for users table, partners.M_id and partners.F_id are FK's referencing to users.id, partners(rowid, f_id, m_id, rate_m, rate_f, score_m, score_f ...more)

Comment: It is almost always beneficial to show the outline schema for the tables. The immediately relevant columns, the primary keys, and any PK/FK relationships between the tables are of most interest.  The Partners table appears to contain columns (M_id, F_id, Rate_M, Rate_F, ...); the PK is not given but might be the combination of (M_id, F_id).  The Users table appears to contain columns (Id, Name, Gender, Age, ...); the Id is probably the PK.  There is an FK from Partners.M_id to Users.Id, and another from Partners.F_id to Users.Id.  Is that about right?  (I'm always suspicious of 'age' columns.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly, so you have to use an indirect mechanism.

One simple option is a UNION:

```
SELECT u.name, u.gender, u.age, p.rate_M, p.rate_F
  FROM users AS u INNER JOIN partners AS p ON u.id = p.M_id AND u.gender = 'M'
UNION
SELECT u.name, u.gender, u.age, p.rate_M, p.rate_F
  FROM users AS u INNER JOIN partners AS p ON u.id = p.F_id AND u.gender = 'F';
```

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, if the Users.Id values are unique, you don't need the `AND gender = 'F'` (or `'M'`) filter conditions; a given user will only appear in the `Partners.M_id` or `Partners.F_id` columns.  It might even be quicker without the filters if the optimizer is really smart (but I suspect it probably isn't - in any of the commercial DBMS or in the Open Source ones such as MySQL or PostgreSQL).